# Remove string from an stdClass object in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called **$field->selectoptions[1]**

print_r($field->selectoptions[1]) gives these results:

```
        stdClass Object ( [voption] => clabels [clabel] => Data Inizio
[values] => Qualsiasi Data 1 Luglio 2016 12 Settembre 2016 14 Novembre
2016 [slabel] => Data Inizio )
```

I need to remove from [values] all invalid dates, in this case "1 Luglio 2016" (July 1st 2016) because the date has passed

I tried using **unset** but that's appears to be a single string.
I don't think a **str_replace** would work either...
Any idea?

Comment: should `Qualsiasi Data` sequence remain unchanged?

Comment: yes, everything must remain the same, only invalid dates need to be removed, like "1 Luglio 2016"

Comment: is the string dynamic or it could have other dates, like `12 Gennaio 2016 ` ? What is the filling format of the `values` key?

Comment: the srting is dynamic. It's an array of products in Joomla Virtuemart each can have its dates of course.
I am in a foreach loop and must remove all invalid dates

Comment: So far I have solved it using json_encode and json_decode as follows:

`$arr=json_encode($field);
             $arr=str_replace($f[1], "", $arr);
             $field=json_decode($arr);`

where $f[1] is the invalid date in my foreach loop